# How to select one element from each column of a matrix to from a new vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a `M`×`N` matrix `A`, and a `M`×`1` index vector `ind`. I want to get a `N`×`1` vector `c` where `c(i) = A(ind(i),i)` for `i`=`1`,`2`,...,`N`.

For example, let

```
A = hilb(5);
ind = [2,3,1,4,2]';
```

How can I get vector `c`?

Comment: Check [`sub2ind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`sub2ind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) does:

```
c = A(sub2ind(size(A), ind(:).', 1:numel(ind)));
```

You can also do it manually to increase speed a little:

```
c = A((0:numel(ind)-1) * size(A,1) + ind(:).');
```

To understand how this works, read on [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/).